# Returning the enclosing object in a method without taking its reference name

Tags: java

In java. How to return the same exceuting object in a return object(same) method without taking the name of the excecuting object as a parameter. For example, suppose there is a method in a class called X(parameters) with the same return type of the class. And I created an Object of the class let it be Y. And I invoke this method by Y.X(par). Can i return Y inside the method from this invocation in a special case.
Is there a way in the java language to do this around other than declaring the method static and taking two paramters?

Consider for the previous example a simple concatenate method.

```
LinkedList concate(LinkedList secondList){
if(secondList.isEmpty()) return (current object);// What is the right form ??
                               // current object is a pseude code not java's
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)?

Comment: @Turing85 I also thought about `this`, but wouldn't that cause issues with the return type?

Comment: @RobinTopper form OP's question: "[...] suppose there is a method in a class called X(parameters) with the same return type of the class." Sounds to me like a typical use case for this or I misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is 'this' operator.

```
LinkedList concate(LinkedList secondList){
if(secondList.isEmpty()) 
    return this;
```

}

By default 'this' returns current instance reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as the method and object belongs to same class, you can write:

```
LinkedList concate(LinkedList secondList){
  if(secondList.isEmpty()) {
    return (this);
  }
 }
```

this holds the reference of current object.